# Magento 2 - Composer update does not fully update core

Tags: magento2, composer

I am on the latest version as of 2.4.1. There is a bug in my shop, I noticed that a file in vendor/magento is responsible for it (vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php).

I noticed that the file differs from the [original latest file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php).

So I executed `composer update` but the file was not changed at all.

In my understanding `composer update` will update the code to the latest version, but this does not seem to work at all. If I delete the file vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php and execute `composer update` then it is not even fetching the file again.

Comment: You can delete vendor dir and run composer clear-cache before composer update

Comment: The whole vendor dir? Then my shop will be offline for a long time. Why did it happen?

Comment: When you run composer update , you have to compile and setup upgrade anyway. So it will be offline. Not sure what differences you see in this file, so we could compare when they was added to magento

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2. Limitation like commit reference

Comment: It depends on your strategy wheter your website gets offline when you execute setup:upgrade. You can also setup a second project and execute setup:upgrade there and just commit the generated code to your production environment.

Comment: This gave me an idea... I just delete the vendor folder on the second project and fetch it again by executing `composer install` and then move it to my not working project and swap it out, then I will have zero downtime.